# UITableView over scroll to bottom but top is normal

Tags: uitableview, uiviewcontroller

#### added in `viewDidLoad`

> navgationBar.translucent =N0, iOS 10.3, xcode 8.3

```
 - (void)__setUpUI{
UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 64)];
[tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"DXGroupMasterLikesCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([DXGroupMasterLikesCell class])];
_tableView = tableView;
_tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.dataSource = self;
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
[self.view addSubview:tableView];}
```

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJJfq.jpg)

but if I set `[self.view addSubview:[UIView new]];` before `[self.view addSubview:tableView];` everything is ok

somebody know why ?

Comment: used `tabbarController`

Comment: set `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` equal to 'YES' could resolve this problem